# i need assistance with this code (python 3.8)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want this script to type out every possible combination of letters, numbers and symbols, even if it would take months to do. Can anyone help?

```py
lower_a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
upper_a = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
num = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

all = lower_a + upper_a + num

def recursive_product(myList, length, myString = ""):
    if length == 0:
        print (myString)
        return
    for c in myList:
        recursive_product(myList, length-1, myString + c)
    
for r in range(1, 3):
    recursive_product(all, r)
```

I found this code from somewhere a little while ago and I want to get it to work with every combination.

Comment: If you enumerate 1 mln combinations per second, then for all N<=10 it will take more than 25 thousand years.

Comment: You have three problems. First: why do you want to do this? Second: you will run out of memory. Third you will run into an RecursionError since Python has a maximum recursion depth in order to prevent a stack overflow.
By the way, welcome to stackoverflow, why don't you [try to reformulate your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: @not_a_bot_no_really_82353 Why would they run out of memory?

Comment: You are trying to find possible combination of letters, numbers and symbols. Every symbol will take memory. Since you can combine an unlimited amount of characters you will need an unlimited amount to store them. Hence this project is literally impossible.
The formular to calculate this is number of characters by the power of length of sentence.
If you only use 50 characters and seek combinations of length 10 you will need to store 9.765625*10^16 characters. About 97656 TB. You will need more RAM than you have disk-space.
That is why OP should reformulate the question.

Comment: @not_a_bot_no_really_82353 he would run out of memory unless you start from 1 character long combination then increase that to 2 character combs then 3... in that case your biggest problem wouldn't be memory it would probably be having to wait to reach a character combination length that would require more memory then what is available.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it iterative:

```
lower_a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
upper_a = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
num = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

for a in lower_a:
    print(a)
    for b in upper_a:
        print(a + b)
        print(b)
        for c in num:
            print(a + c)
            print(c + b)
            print(a + b + c)
            print(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way you can do it:

```
lower_a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
upper_a = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
num = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

all = lower_a + upper_a + num


def words(combinations,length,prefix =""):
    if(len(prefix)>=length):
        return prefix
    for i in range(len(combinations)):
        print(words(combinations,length, prefix+all[i]))
```

running `words(all,3)` would print all possible 3 character combinations

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the cartesian product of all the combinations (e.g. `aA0` to `zZ9`),

```
import itertools
import string

for x in itertools.product(string.ascii_lowercase, string.ascii_uppercase, string.digits):
    print(''.join(x))
```

If you're looking for all the possible combinations of length 3,

```
import itertools
import string

for x in itertools.combinations(string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, 3):
    print(''.join(x))
```